# Is the "close" function a good alternative to the "with" keyword in Python?

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

Hello stackoverflow community,

I read that the advantage of using a `with` statement in Python is that it is guaranteed to close a resource / file no matter how the nested block exits. Since I want to use the resource / file object beyond a single nested block I was wondering if the use of the `close` function would be equal in conjunction with a proper exception handling.

Example:

```
try:
    # Create a new file with the desired name
    csv_file = open(filename, mode="x", encoding='utf-8')

except OSError:
    # Make sure to close the resource / file correctly
    print("An exception occurred during the csv file creation")
    csv_file.close()

else:
    print("Created new csv file")
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. `with` is a convenience you don't have to use if you need another approach. `with` uses the Context Manager Protocol to get the file to close itself, just the same as calling `close()`.

Comment: The choice of whether to use a context manager, or be careful to use the close after  the open, is use case dependent, but both are valid Python

Comment: `with` is a relatively new addition to Python, and it was added to make things easier and safer. There's certainly no requirement to use it.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was more to it than convenience. Thank you very much for the clarification sj95126, paisanco and Mark Ransom.